# How to automate making entities to implement IEntity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I have a custom interface IEntity. I want my Entity Framework generated POCO entities to derive from IEntity. For now; i am adding one partial class for each Entity Framework entity and define;

```
public partial class Person : IEntity
{
}

public partial class City : IEntity
{
}
```

Is there any more elegant way of doing this by reflection or IoC containers?

Note: I want to have the possibility of not implementing IEntity for some entities in some cases.

Note2: I dont want to edit any tt or edmx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to T4 template which generates entities (Something.tt), find line

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#>
```

This line generates class opening string for each entity, e.g.

```
public class Foo
```

And replace it with

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#> : IEntity
```

Now generate entity definitions will look like

```
public class Foo : IEntity
```

You will also probably need to add namespace using, if IEntity defined in different namespace (a little weird case I think).

Comment: Thanks but i do not want to edit any generation file like tt or edmx. I want to do this by code. And yes; IEntity is defined in a different dll/namespace.

Comment: @ozdogan reflection will not help you here. Reflection uses metadata of already compiled code. Can you explain why editing entity generation template does not fit your needs?

Comment: Seems like it would be tricky to maintain having an interface just magically inject itself at run time as well. I'd go with t4 as well if I did not want to manually add the IEntity. You could make your DAL require a type of IEntity that was you ensure anyone using them has to implement it.

Comment: Agree with Tony. Also if you need some entities not to implement this interface - you are free to write method in template, which will return implemented by entity interfaces based on your conditions. You are not forced to hard-code interface implementation for each generated entity

Answer (score 0):

You can always make an Item Template. So when you do Add New => Entity Type  instead of say the normal class type. So if you create an "Entity Type" it comes with IEntity already implemented/inherited whatever you set up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/20/visual-studio-custom-templates.aspx

Then its not "long term" generation, it will just generate it when you create the file but yet it will automatically be there.